# Kotlin List of Stuctures

Tags: kotlin

Hi how would I do this?

---

```
Structure TITLE
  value.l
  string.s
EndStructure

NewList mylist.TITLE()

AddElement(mylist())
mylist()\value = 0
mylist()\string = "hello world"
```

---

Obviously the above is not Java or Kotlin, it's actually how we create lists in PureBasic cannot figure out how this works in kotlin.

Advise would be appeached.

Comment: Your use case looks like a `data class`. You can check them out [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html). I would recommend browsing through an introductory book on Kotlin. As you're already experienced in a different language you can pick up Kotlin rather easily.

Comment: Read this to learn about how lists work in Kotlin. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collections-overview.html

Comment: data class Card(val c_title: String, var c_message :String, var c_link :String, var c_timer :String,  var c_rolldice :String, var c_image :String )

var mydecklist = mutableListOf<Card>()

only part I'm now missing other than cleaning up for a new deck list, is how to add data to the class parameters.

mydecklist.add(0, "card title" )  

According to the obvious error message by the compiler, that it's expecting a "Card", I'm not sure how to proceed from here, as all examples I've seen don't handle this method of using mutableListOf()

Comment: funny how that works you post something for help and minutes later you figure out how something works :), unlike some people who just get on with their day and ignore and then frustration anyone else who google searches.             
mydecklist.add(0,Card(card_title,card_message,card_link,card_timer,card_rolldice,card_image)) , should make the penny drop for anyone else that might stumble on my post in the future.

Comment: @MelonySharon Can you post the answer you've found and mark it? So that this question can be closed. No ones going to see unformated, single line code inside a comment, so an `answer` would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response.

`mydecklist.add(0,Card(card_title,card_message,card_link,card_timer,card_rolldice,card_image))`

Should make the penny drop for anyone else that might stumble on my post in the future